# Arduino concat operators make String null

Tags: c, string, arduino, operators, arduino-uno

I am making an Arduino project, and I am just wondering why the following code, when sends a string to the Serial, creates new lines but with null text. It is as if the + operator makes strings null.

### This code works

```
String stringOne = "This is a string";
Serial.println(stringOne);
```

When placed in a loop, the Serial repeatedly prints "This is a string" in new lines just like it's supposed to.

### This code does not work

```
int number = 1234567890;
String stringOne = "This is a number. It is:";
String stringTwo = String(number);
String stringThree = stringOne + stringTwo;
Serial.println(stringThree);
```

When placed in a loop, the Serial makes new lines, but does not print anything, as if the strings were null.

If I can receive any help, I would greatly appriciate it. Thanks in advance

Comment: does it help putting stringOne + stringTwo in a constructor for String?

Comment: no same results. @chris

Comment: Does this code work if you put it in its own sketch?

Comment: Yes, but oddly the number goes from 1234567890 to 722... The other parts of the string are okay. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the original problem exists is because you're out of SRAM; `stringThree` gets created in an area of the memory map where everything always reads as 0, and 0 indicates the end of the underlying `char*`. Shove as many constants and literals as possible into flash instead.

The reason it doesn't work properly in a new sketch is because `int` in AVR is only 16 bits long, and you're trying to stuff a 32-bit number into it; try using `long` instead.

Comment: That was it! I looked it up on [Arduino.cc](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memory) Thank you so much for the suggestion! @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams